System network connection
I tried installing a vpn (hide.me) then uninstalled it since I was not able to use it. After uninstalling the vpn, my Ubuntu was no longer connecting to the internet. It shows that the internet is available and running but I can't use it even to browse, I tried restarting the network Manager, It brought back the connection but its speed is not good or is not normal. It can't open even an email. How can I resolve this issue? While using Ubuntu 22

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What version of Ubuntu are you running? Please run lsb_release -a and Edit your question to include this information.
